# How to check if a given tweet can be retweeted or not?

Tags: python, api, twitter, oauth

Currently am working on a retweet function using twitter API's. While the feature works fine, but who those tweets that are not retweetable i get this error, "sharing is not permissable for this status (Share validations failed)".

So i need a way to determine if a particular tweet is retweetable or not using the JSON returned by the statuses/:id API. Is it possible??

Based on this i need to place a retweet button only for those tweets that are eligible for retweet.

In original twitter website, i see the following tweets are not retweetable.

1. My own tweets
2. Tweets of my followers who had set it to protected.

Please explain more about this to me.

Answer (score 1):

If someone have protected his tweets, it means his tweets can only be seen by his followers. If you retweet these tweets it may break this protection. So twitter do not let you retweet these tweets

If you want to check whether a user have protected his tweets or not, you can try this API:

```
http://api.twitter.com/version/users/show.format
```

The result of this API contains a field name "protected", if "protected" is set to true, you can't retweet his tweets

Document is here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show

Comment: Ya that is correct. But is there any field that says a particular tweet can be retweeted? Or i should make my own checks to see if they are protected or if the author and the recipient are one and the same? In these cases i should not enable the retweet button right?

Comment: You should make your own checks